# Direct payments between users on Django based website

Tags: django, paypal, payment, payment-processing

I am building a website that should allow users to buy stuff from each other. I don't want to be involved in money transactions at all. It will be pretty much something like eBay. Card payments are not a must. Basically user views an item added by another user, clicks on a buy button and finishes the payment using third-party service.

The application will be based on Django and I was thinking of PayPal. I also do not want to pay for Premium accounts as I am not planning to charge users or earn money in any way. Could you please give me some advice on what is the best solution for this kind of project? I have been doing some research on the Internet but I am still quite confused.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am personally a huge fan of [Stripe](https://stripe.com/). It's much easier to work with than PayPal and also much easier to implement. It allows you to add transaction fees if you wish.

I'd read up on it, as it has quite a few solutions ranging from inclusion of a simple JavaScript file that creates Checkout/Pay buttons to designing a custom checkout flow.

Their [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs) is extensive, highly geared toward developers, and worth the read.

Good luck!

Comment: No problem. I'd also like to add that for your scenario, your customers/users will need to register for their own accounts to be able to accept payments and will provide you with their API information. This will mesh with one of their libraries which is escaping my thoughts right now, and allow you to take a flat fee or percentage from the seller's profit.